# How Do I hide O365 Menu inside New view of site content in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, css

[image]

[image]

The CSS code I used to hide O365 menu is:

```
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-leftAlign { 
  display: none !important; https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhmC.jpg
}
```

However when I open up site content inside new office view O365 menu appear. How do I hide this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has disabled all Branding in Modern Experiences

If you think they are wrong, raise your voice:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th